# How to add info like the shown image in Gantt chart in ms project 2007?

Tags: ms-project

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHlM2.jpg)

I have to add information to the Gantt chart like the shown image for the project created. without doing the edit  in adobe pdf. I know that is possible in adobe but i want to do it in ms-project 2007 itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer : File---> Page Setup--->Footer--->Left or Center or Right

Choose according to your requirement and enter the data.

[Answer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX9wD.png)